# OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.0.0.0' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

Tags: mysql, docker, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to connect a FastAPI with sqlAlchemy to a mysql db container.

I am using the alias. Unfortunately it wont connect and I don't know why.

Using MySQL Workbench on the external port with the environment variables works to connect.

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://root:3091@db:3306/investing"
```

Here is the docker compose file

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services: 
  db:
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=investing
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=3091
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    ports: 
      - "3307:3306"
    restart: on-failure
    volumes: 
      - "./db/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    # healthcheck:
    #   test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD


  # client:
  #   build: client
  #   ports: [3000]
  #   restart: always

  server:
    build: server
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./server:/tmp
      - ./server/data:/tmp/data
```

Docker PS

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                         PORTS                                                  NAMES
cccbd4651340   react-flask-app_server   "python /tmp/app.py"     47 minutes ago   Restarting (0) 6 seconds ago                                                          react-flask-app_server_1
690185103a7b   mysql:8.0.28             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   47 minutes ago   Up 45 seconds                  33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp, :::3307->3306/tcp   react-flask-app_db_1
```

Comment: The error message in the title doesn't match the database URI in the question; are you sure the database location is actually getting set correctly?  (Are the `volumes:` hiding setup work that's being done in the `server/Dockerfile`?)

Comment: @DavidMaze Ah sorry right you are so what happened was I had it set to db:3306 and then when that didnt work I tried 0.0.0.0 and also localhost. Hopefully that clarifies it as well for anyone else. I simply grabbed the wrong log in the docker logs

Comment: `0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp` in your `docker ps` output indicates that the container is listening for connections on external port 3307 from any IP address and forwarding them to internal port 3306. So, if you want to connect from outside the container you'll need to connect on port 3307. (TCP connections from within the container would connect to localhost on port 3306.)

Comment: @GordThompson the external mapping is only for easier insight into the database from the host. The sqlalchemy server connection is via another docker container. Please not that when I had this set dyanmically as [3306] the outcome was the same. I added the external mapping to ensure the db was working correctly. I should be able to connect externally and internally if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hilariously enough, in converting from Flask to FastAPI, I had forgotten to uncomment the uvicorn to actually properly run the server. Bit of a woops there xD.

```py
# uvicorn.run(host="0.0.0.0", port="5000")
```

I'm completely surprised that it was giving me an inability to connect instead of a pure exit code 0 with no logs. That really threw me off.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("app:app", host="0.0.0.0", port="5000")
```

PS. my main file is app.py not main.py hence app:app not main:app